# Open a link in the android browser (WebView)

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I recently implemented the shouldInterceptRequest method to detect when the link "http://sitemercado.com.br/valida" clicked to open it in the android browser instead of opening internally in the webview until it worked the link is opened in the browser but when I come back for the webview application, it is also loaded, I would like it to load only in the browser.

My code is the following:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pb = (findViewById(R.id.pb));
        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.setListener(this, this);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.sitemercado.com.br/frade");
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, off.class);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                finish();
            }
        });

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.sitemercado.com.br/valida")) {
                    return true;

                }
                String valida = "https://www.sitemercado.com.br/valida";
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(valida));
                startActivity(i);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1Detectou", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return false;
                }
        });
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, the following is just wrong:

```
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.sitemercado.com.br/valida")) {
                return true;

            }
            String valida = "https://www.sitemercado.com.br/valida";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(valida));
            startActivity(i);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1Detectou", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return false;
        }
    });
```

You're getting the host of the URL, then comparing it to a full URL. That's never going to be equal.

Then you launch the link only if that statement is false? That's inverted, since you say in your question that you want it to launch in the browser only if the URL is `/valida`. The way you have it, no matter what URL you attempt to load, Android will launch a browser pointing to `/valida`.

Try this instead:

```
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getPath().contains("valida")) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1Detectou", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```